# php curl_exec returns response as 1

Tags: php, curl, magento2, php-curl

I am trying to use curl as below code snippet.  I already tried all options i could search for the similar issue. have added all setopt options availabale but still i get response as 1. I am trying post request to server and expecting json response. What am I missing?

```
 $logger->info('url:'.$service_url);
    $curl = curl_init();
    $curl_post_data = array(
        'username' => 'user1',
        'password' => 'welcome'
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ));

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));


    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $logger->info('curl_response 11:'.print_r($curl_response));
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);

    }
    $logger->info('response ok!');
    $logger->info('decoded:'.print_r($decoded));
```

**Updated for solution:**
as suggested just used print_r($curl_response, true) to log the response, and used print_r($decoded['orderId']) to get the specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_r()` ***prints*** its output, it doesn't ***return*** it. In order to store the output of a call to `print_r()` in a variable, or send it to a logger or whatnot, you need to pass a truthy value as the second parameter.

```
$x = print_r($foo); // prints formatted $foo and returns true

$x = print_r($foo, true); // prints nothing and returns formatted $foo
```

Note: Since you've set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true, the call to `curl_exec()` will already return a string. There's really no need to pass that through `print_r()`, just dump the string.

Also note: You'll want to verify that `json_decode()` doesn't return `null`. And you'll likely also want to verify that the HTTP status code is 200 (which you can do via `curl_getinfo()`.

Comment: To be noted: `mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )` _When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. **Otherwise, the return value is TRUE**._ (emphasis mine)

Comment: Just a reason as to _why_ it's returning `1`, as php reads `1` as `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really don't intend to use print_r function. I just wanted log the response in log file to verify if I am getting any response or not. I am expecting a json response something like { "orderId": "39018" }. I will try to get the orderId instead. $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);$logger->info('decoded:'.$decoded['orderId']);